# How to detect there are no available formats in HTML5 video?

Tags: html, video, format, fallback

This code shows messages for old browsers that does not support `video` element.

```
<video controls>
    <source src="./foo.mp4" />
    <p>Use new browser.</p>
</video>
```

Firefox supports `video` element and MP4/H.264 format in Windows 7+ but does not support that format in Windows XP.

I'd like to show messages for Windows XP users to install plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way (if I understand the question correctly) would be to have your video element with the default fall-back mechanism, and then supplement it using JavaScript for specific format detection and if you don't find a supported format, even though the video element is there display an alternate message

```
canPlayType(format)
```

Tests to see whether the browser can play a specific type of video, for example `'video/webm;codecs="vp8, vorbis"'`

The browser will return:

- `probably` - if it’s most likely the video file can be played `maybe`
- if the video might be playable `[empty string]`
- if the video file is not playable

---

```
<video id="myvid" controls>
    <source src="./foo.mp4" />
    <p>Use new browser.</p>
</video>
<script>
    myvid = document.getElementById("myvid")
    if (myvid.canPlayType('video/webm;codecs="vp8, vorbis"') || myvid.canPlayType('... others depending on what formats you have available ...') {
        // all okay
    } else {
        // alert user to the problem
    }
</script>
```